# yii2-rbac-mongodb : getRule() function return false

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, rbac

I am using the extension https://github.com/letyii/yii2-rbac-mongodb and it show error :

> "Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException Rule not
>   found: userGroup"

When I debug I found that function `getRule()` of class `BaseManager` return the false instead of below:

```
common\rbac\UserGroupRule Object
(
[name] => userGroup
[createdAt] => 1424853596
[updatedAt] => 1424853596
)
```

When I rewrite the `getRule()` method as below it is running:

```
public function getRule($name) {

    $row = (new Query)->select(['data'])
        ->from($this->ruleTable)
        ->where(['name' => $name])
        ->one($this->db);        
  $data = 'O:25:"common\rbac\UserGroupRule":3:{s:4:"name";s:9:"userGroup";s:9:"createdAt";i:1424853596;s:9:"updatedAt";i:1424853596;}';

//    return $row === false ? null : @unserialize($row['data']);  
return $row === false ? null : @unserialize($data);
}
```

my `rbac_auth_rule` collection document:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5502ba013d261e5d0f5cae96"),
"name" : "userGroup",
"data" : "O:25:'common/rbac/UserGroupRule':3:  {s:4:'name';s:9:'userGroup';s:9:'createdAt';i:1424853596;s:9:'updatedAt';i:1424853596;}",
"created_at" : "1424853596",
"updated_at" : "1424853596"
}
```